# How do I use a disable method in combination of another initialization?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am using the following autocomplete plugin: http://www.richwidgets.io/api/classes/autocomplete.html

What I would like to achieve, is to have all fields with the class `.autocomplete` be transformed into autocomplete fields, BUT the one that are disabled, to be disabled using the plugin's method ("`disable`").

I currently use the following, but seems to result in errors:

```
$('.autocomplete').each(function(){
   $(this).autocomplete({..});
   if($(this).is(':disabled')){
       $(this).autocomplete('disable');
   }
}
```

P.s. the code that is between brackets ( {..} ) works, I double checked. It's really what happens next ;-)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong..

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I put your sample in [a fiddle and it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/402rw9gg/), the error must be elsewhere. Could you make a MCVE?

Comment: That's strange. Well, the error I'm getting is as follows: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Comment: Well that looks like the widget thinks a `null` object is a function. Double check that you're supplying a valid `source` option (which afaik is the only mandatory one). To provide any further help i'd need more details. You might want to [check out the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emozio/hmso0f5j/) and it does work, but I get tons of errors, especially compared to yours...